# Asterisk as WebRTC MCU and External Authentication

Tags: xmpp, sip, asterisk, webrtc, sip-server

I have a website with an integrated and customizable chat system ( based on XMPP ).

I have tried many WebRTC framework like [licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/), [muaz-khan's](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RTCMultiConnection), jinja's plugin, [OpenTok](http://tokbox.com/opentok) for WebRTC and other, but neither of them had enough reliability ( especially on multi user conversation ).

So I decided to rely on most tested, stable & reliable SIP Server ( like Asterisk ), joined to WebRTC or Flash clients ( like [sip5ml](http://sipml5.org/) ).

The problem is: I don't want to insert and synchronize 2 account's table ( WebSite & Asterisk ), can I insert them only a time, and let asterisk fetch them realtime?

Comment: Have you looked into Kamailio and Asterisk integration it has some nice and clean integration. Kamailio can be used as your SIP SBC WS for your remote clients and Asterisk can be your Media servers

Answer (score 0):

You can use asterisk realtime with mysql view(so view  looks like asterisk expect.

Other solution is mysql trigger.

Comment: is creating a view on sipusers' table enough? I have seen that it has many parameters and not only user/pass. Have you found any reference? thanks